# ¿Cómo instalar una aplicación Android en el emulador de Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Hola estaba intentando **instalar *aplicaciones Android* en el emulador de *Eclipse***. Cuando intento hacer la instalación arrastrándolas y soltándolas en el emulador, obtengo el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo intente también por medio de consola pero me devuelve lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna manera de instalar aplicaciones desde fuera del `emulador Android de Eclipse` pero para probarlas con éste?

Captura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te está indicando que el sistema de ficheros es de sólo lectura, prueba a montarlo en modo escritura con `mount -o remount,rw /system` desde `adb shell` como super usuario.

Comment: pero estoy en windows yo lo que hago es  `adb -s emulator-5554 install Cleaner.apk` como sería con adb shell?, pobre en modo super usuario con el comando que cite pero devuelve lo mismo no probe con eso de adb shell.

Comment: Una vez con el emulador abierto haces `adb shell` y se abrirá una consola que se estará ejecutando en el emulador, ahí te pones como super usuario con `su` y vuelves a montar como escritura el sistema de archivos con el comando que te escribí

Comment: Supongo que tendré que estudiar la linea de comandos porque cuando pongo tu comando me pone `Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory` Supongo que las opciones no estarán bien o algo de esto puse `mount -o remount,rw /system`

Comment: Ahora no puedo probarlo, verifica que están bien los espacios (entre la w y la /), el guión y la o van juntos, etc

Comment: Hice esto remount rw /system, pero al instalarlo de nuevo me muestra `C:\Users\android\Desktop\test\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-t
ools>adb -s emulator-5554 install Cleaner.apk
Cleaner.apk: 1 file pushed. 0.4 MB/s (68654 bytes in 0.151s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Cleaner.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
rm failed for -f, Read-only file system`

Comment: Es `mountESPACIO-oESPACIOremount,rwESPACIO/system` sustituyendo la palabra ESPACIO por un espacio :)

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje indicado

> INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES

Indica que la aplicación que estas tratando de instalar se firmó con una llave  diferente a la copia que esta instalada en el dispositivo o emulador.

Este mensaje es el mostrado cuando se intenta realizar esta operación desde Android Studio,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que al aceptar lo que realiza en realidad es eliminar la aplicación instalada e instala la nueva que contiene una firma diferente, puedes verlo en los comandos del `adb` que realiza:

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.mypackage.myapp
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.mypackage.myapp"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.mypackage.myapp
Success
```

Como solución puedes eliminar la aplicación instalada e instalar nuevamente.

Comment: Hola cuando dices esto  
`El mensaje indicado

INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES
Indica que la aplicación que estas tratando de instalar se firmó con una llave diferente a la copia que esta instalada en el dispositivo o emulador.` quieres decir que ya se instalado pero con una llave diferente?

Comment: si! en tu dispositivo o emulador existe una versión de la aplicación.  En algunos casos asegura realizar la desinstalación con la opción "uninstall for all users".